# Field extensions and Intermediate Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $E/K$ be a field extension. Show the following equivalence:

(i) E/K is algebraic

(ii) Every Intermediate Ring of $E/K$ is a Field.

Here is what I tried:

(i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) Let $E/K$ be algebraic. We need to show that for two Elements $a,b \in R$ the multiplicative Inverse also is in $R$. Let $R$ be a Intermediate Ring of $E/K$. Then there are is Set $A$ with $K(A)=R$. Let $a,b\in A$ with $a\neq0$. Let's consider $K(a,b)\subseteq R$. Since $a,b$ are algebraic elements, the extension $K(a,b)/K$ is finite $\Rightarrow$ all elements of $K(a,b)$ are algebaric over K, so $a+b, a-b, ab, 1/a \in K(a,b)\subseteq R$.

(ii)$\Rightarrow$(i) 
Let $R$ be a Intermediate Ring of $E/K$ and $a\in E$. We know that $K[a]$ is a field, so $a^{-1}\in K[a]$. Now $K[a]:= \{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_ia^{i_1} : x_i\in K, i_j\in \mathbb{N}\}$, so there is a $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_ia^{i_1} = a^{-1} \Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_ia^{i_1+1} = 1 \Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_ia^{i_1+1} - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow$ a is algebraic.

Is this proof ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of the proof is correct, though you don't need to consider an arbitrary intermediate ring $R$, only the specific $K[a]$ for a given nonzero element $a\in E$.

However, in the first part when you write $R=K(A)$, (at least the notation seems to suggest that) you implicitly assumed the conslusion, that $R$ is a field.
We only need that $R\subseteq E$ and so every nonzero element $a\in R$ is algebraic over $K$, implying $a^{-1}\in K[a]\subseteq R$.

Comment: Thank you. I think it would be correct if I would write $R=K[A]$. Can I leave the rest for the first part?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure we can always write $R=K[A]$. Nevertheless, for any $a,b\in R$, their sum and difference and product is obviously in $R$, as it is a subring, and for the inverse of an $a\in R$ we can purely use that $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: Thanks again, how can we use that $a$ is algebraic?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, if $0\ne a\in R$, then $K[a]\subseteq R$, and as $a$ is algebraic, we have $a^{-1}\in K[a]$.